# HttpClient aborting simple get request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am doing a simple Get request with HttpClient. But I am have issues with it aborting before the request is complete. Fiddler shows that it the request should return a 200, but it shows that the request was aborted. It is diffenitally not hitting the default 100s timeout. Is there any hidden setting I am missing?

```
var new_client = new HttpClient();
var req = await new_client.GetAsync("http://a20.skout.com/support/captchaMobile/?sid=e91af660-0b3d-4c2f-bbdd-249506b9c440");
req.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

[image: Image of fiddler request. Shows sucess 200 status code but aborted.]

Image of fiddler request. Showing a sucessful 200 status code but aborted by the client.

Update1: use sid to try "36598189-0f2f-45b9-a794-385a5d5e11c8"

Update2: I am also having problem with this url "http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Lc2qN8SAAAAAEe8_R2ALF4hu1V_x34nUV1mzW-W"

Update3: So I manage to get a response with `new_client.GetAsync("http://a20.skout.com/support/captchaMobile/?sid=e91af660-0b3d-4c2f-bbdd-249506b9c440").Result`. I am unsure why that works but not await. I guess it has to be done syncronously. I will leave the question up just incase someone has a more vaild answer.

Comment: Likely, Fiddler considers a request aborted when the TCP connection is closed prematurely. So my guess is that your code does not wait for the response to be read (since asynchrony is involved) and your console app exits killing the TCP connection. There's a bug in that you are not waiting for the response to complete. Likely, the function that this code is in returns a Task that is not awaited (or waited on).

Comment: I used `var req = await` but it for some reason `await` causes it to abort. I had to call it synchronously with by getting the `.Result`.

Comment: Did you consider what I said? Using Result is a workaround that likely depends on a race condition or a very brittle constellation in your code. This is not the right fix.

Comment: I tried using await, but it is simply not awaiting. It is only that function that is causing a problem.